# Where comparison on join table with buffer value on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

**How can I use the join table's column value with arithmetic operation during the where condition on Rails?**

`User` and `Order` are the two Schema, `Order` has `user` via Foreign key relation

My goal is to find if an Order was created/placed within 5 minutes of User creation (Understanding Users who signup for placing an Order)

*Tried the following queries*

`Order.where('country': 'US').joins(:user).where('orders.created_at <= :u_date', {u_date: 'users.created_at' + 5.minutes })`

With this query we get the following error `no implicit conversion of Time into String`, so the `users.created_at` is not evaluating into a Date

Hence tried converting the string to DateTime objects, which failed too

`Order.joins(:user).where('orders.created_at < ?', 'users.created_at'+ 5.minutes)`

How can I do the comparison inside the Where query?
Right now I am plucking the data and comparing it, It'd be great to make it work inside the Where or any relevant query itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're invoking `+` on a string passing as argument a Time object, which is not an out-of-the-box operation, at least in Rails.

If the time to add is not dynamic you could try;

```
where("orders.created_at <= users.created_at + INTERVAL '5.minutes'")
```

which makes your DBMS add the proper interval to `users.created_at` (in this case I'm assuming Postgresql)